# How to prefill the form in react with values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code

```
    ....
       const { userProfile, getUserProfile } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfile();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
         const [user, setUser] = useState({
           name: userProfile.name,
           email: userProfile.email,
           password: "",
           password2: "",
         });
         const { name, email, password, password2 } = user;
         const onChange = (e) =>
           setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
           
        const onSubmit = (e) => {
           e.preventDefault();
           console.log('hi')//for instance
         }
```

the component returns the following

```
              <Form.Group controlId="formGroupEmail">
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="name"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  maxLength="30"
                  
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="formGroupEmail">
                <Form.Control
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="formGroupPassword">
                <Form.Control
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  minLength="6"
                  
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="formGroupPassword">
                <Form.Control
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  name="password2"
                  value={password2}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  minLength="6"
                  
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
```

I want my form to be prefilled with the above state as I am working on edit user details functionality
But when I execute it The form did not prefill with the name & email as usual it is empty
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did the below answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

It is not getting initialized, probably, because `userProfile` is empty when you `useState` to initialize the `user` state.

To fix it, you can `useEffect` hook to update the `user`:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  name: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  password2: '',
}) // initialize with empty

useEffect(() => {
  setUser(prev => ({
    name: userProfile.name,
    email: userProfile.email,
    password: prev.password,
    password2: prev.password2,
  }))
}, [userProfile]) // setUser when userProfile changes
```